# Get the last record of group using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a list:

```
var list = new List<Foo>() {
     new Foo() { FooId = 1, GroupId = 1, ValueA = 3}, 
     new Foo() { FooId = 2,GroupId = 1, ValueA = 40}, 
     new Foo() { FooId = 3,GroupId = 2, ValueA = 80}, 
     new Foo() { FooId = 4, GroupId = 2, ValueA = 20}, 
};
```

I want to just get the latest record so the result would be like:

```
| GroupId | ValueA |
|---------|--------|
|     1   |   40   | 
|     2   |   20   |
```

Comment: What is "the latest"? Is it always the biggest `ValueA` for a `GroupId`?

Comment: No .. the record with the latest index

Comment: I can't see an index in your `Foo` class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on what you want you can change `OrderBy` or even can use `First` or `Last` in this.

```
list
  .OrderByDescending(a => a.ValueA)
  .GroupBy(a => a.GroupId)
  .Select(g => g.Last());
```

Comment: Thank you .. that was exactly what I needed

Comment: But that differs from your statement, that it isn't always the biggest `ValueA`but the index?!

Comment: I explained that I wanted the latest record not the record with the biggest ValueA .. and also I provided my desired reault which contains ValueA 20 for group 2 which clearly is not the biggest ValueA .. but thank you anyway your answer helped in another condition

Comment: I had to do something similar but what bothers me is what happens when I want to get the latest row of a database that can have store some thousands of records per day? For more than 500.000 records stored isn't the OrderByDescending  going to slow down the execution?

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = 
    ( from   p in List
      group  p by p.Value into g
      select new { 
        GroupId = g.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id).FirstOrDefault().GroupId,
        ValueA = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault().ValueA 
      }
    ).ToList();
```

It works for me...
So you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

```
var result1 = from p in list
    group p by p.GroupId into g
    select new { GroupId = g.Key, MaxFooId = g.FooId.Max() };

var result2 = from p in result1
    join list q on p.MaxFooId equals q.FooId
    select new { GroupId = p.GroupId, ValueA = q.ValueA }
```